# Error unacceptable content-type: application/xml

Tags: ios, objective-c

my code is:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html",nil];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

I got the error:

> unacceptable content-type: application/xml

Comment: So response from server is in XML type.

Comment: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/xml" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60800002eec0> { URL: http:... } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 4;
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
    Date = "Sat, 30 Sep 2017 18:21:03 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://...., com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/xml}

Comment: Your server is apparently returning XML, so you'd use `AFXMLParserResponseSerializer` instead of `AFJSONResponseSerializer`. Also, I wouldn't suggest messing around with `acceptableContentTypes` (because that's set appropriately for you already). The only time you should be playing with `acceptableContentTypes` is when dealing with a server that returns the wrong `Content-Type` header for the content provided (and even then, it's better to fix the web service).

Comment: You need to read the documentation of your API. It's useless to think it will returns JSON if it can't, and returns XML. Check if there is a possibility for it to returns JSON, else it's XML, and it's another parsing you need to use.